# Getting portions of javascript to fire before entire function(s) finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing a image via jQuery, but the image takes a few seconds to load and hence appears like the click did nothing, so I needed to input a temporary "loading" image to show the user that the image is loading.

However as I have experienced in the past JS doesn't really fire things as things happen, it waits until the full function is done before things happen; I recall coming up with a solution in the past but I just can't remember what it was.

I have this which does each task, but the user never sees the loading image because it is replaced by the new image before the user even sees anything.

```
function changeMainImage(image) {

    // Set temporary loading image
    jQuery('#main_image').attr('src', 'images/loading.jpeg');    

    // Set big image
    var big_image = image + '-big.png'

    // Update main image url
    jQuery('#main_image').attr('src', big_image);

}
```

I have tried putting the below into a separate function:

```
// Set temporary loading image
jQuery('#main_image').attr('src', 'images/loading.jpeg');
```

..and calling it before the other function like so..

```
onclick="setLoadingIMage(); changeMainImage('images/ai');"
```

but that didn't change anything.

Could anyone tell me what I need to do to achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will display the `loading.jpeg` until the image has been loaded.

```
function changeMainImage(image) {

    jQuery('#main_image').attr('src', 'images/loading.jpeg');

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = image + "-big.png";

    img.onload = function( ) {
          jQuery('#main_image').attr('src', img.src );
    }
}
```

If the image is held in cache then `img.onload` will fire immediately.

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/3x63F/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<label id="label"> Loading </label>
<img src="src" id="image" style="display:none;"/>
```

JS:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var label = document.getElementById('label');

image.onload = function(){
    image.style.display = "block";
    label.style.display = "none";
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3x63F/ (the image is too big, so it may take several minutes to load)

Comment: Not cross browser for cached/broken image. Better would be to use a plugin as https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: @roasted you can check if image loading failed and do waht you want- image.onerror = function(){ //... }

Comment: @roasted cached image will load imediatelly, so I don't see any problem

Comment: But can you check 'easily' if an image come from cache?

Comment: No, cached image in some browser will not fired onload event. So here, your image will remain hidden.

Comment: Why do you need to check that? image will load so fast that loading will not appear

Comment: Works in ie9 and chrome (have not tested in other browsers)

Comment: In older browser as IE7/opera and older version of chrome (wich should not be a problem here as chrome use auto update). Ive tested your code using IE9 emulating IE7 and your code works as expected. But thats is not straight IE7, so cannot be sure on whats going on here. You are using plain javascript which is a good point. So +1 as your solution seems to works on all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick I use for this:

1. Embed image in a div
2. Keep a loading image as a background of the Div
3. When the image is loaded, it is displayed hiding the loading background behind.

Hope this works for you. Also, you may choose an animated gif for loading image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial of how to accomplish showing the spinner in the foreground while the image is loading in background

[Image Loading Spinner](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/)